# Azure Event Hub How to get Latest messages

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Python Function app to read events from event hub and process it. The message retention period of event hub is 7 days. I found that the messages received from the event hub is not the latest one, but it is 7 days old. Anyone please let me know how to get the latest message from event hub. I am new to Azure cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is currently worked on by Functions Team - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/issues/64

Comment: The feature that you mentioned is for .Net I think. No info regarding the python.

Comment: You are right. Currently there is no such option in Azure.

Comment: Any related info regarding python? I appreciate in advance.